# Horizontal Trees in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I've made a tree in the dot language, similar to the one [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/unix.html).

Is there any way I could get the tree to expand to the right, instead of downwards (so the root node is on the left and children go along to the right).

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @snoobdogg: the link is ok again

Answer (score 120, accepted):

it's very easy, as long as you stick to basic layout: place [rankdir](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/docs/attrs/rankdir/)="LR" near top definition. Something like

```
digraph unix {
  size="6,6";
  rankdir="LR";
  ...
}
```